# Register 2 senderIds in JavaScript FCM

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, token

On a web page, I'm trying to create 2 firebase apps, with different names, each one associated with a different senderId.
I'm basically doing this:

```
    const init = async ()=>{
        const senderId1 = "SENDERID_1";
        const senderId2 = "SENDERID_2";

        const firebase1 = firebase.initializeApp({"messagingSenderId": senderId1},`name${senderId1}`);
        const firebase2 = firebase.initializeApp({"messagingSenderId": senderId2},`name${senderId2}`);

        const messaging1 = firebase1.messaging();
        const messaging2 = firebase2.messaging();

        await messaging1.requestPermission();
        await messaging2.requestPermission();

        const token1 = await messaging1.getToken(senderId1,"FCM");
        const token2 = await messaging2.getToken(senderId2,"FCM");

        document.querySelector("#token1").innerHTML = token1;
        document.querySelector("#token2").innerHTML = token2;
        document.querySelector("#areTheSame").innerHTML = (token1 == token2);
    };
    init();
```

[Here's a page that exemplifies this behaviour](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/tests/testfcmbugreport.html).

The code doesn't generate any errors but token1 is always the same as token2. Obviously I need them to be different. Seems like a caching issue?

Does anyone have any idea if there's a workaround for this?
Thanks in advance